# Drag & Drop Elements in a ListView -Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm looking for a way to drag and drop elements in a ListView template within Django, is this possible?

To be more specific, I'm looking for a logged in user (NOT superuser) who has access to only their own content to be able to move their entries around and it saves to the database in that order so the next time they log in it's still in the new order.

If drag and drop isn't possible, some other ideas I have are up/down arrows or a box to manually edit the order number and save it that way.

Any help in figuring this out or pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated! I'm pretty new to Python/Django, so if I didn't give enough info on what I need, let me know and I'll try to explain better!

Thanks.